# How to change the language in a website (datascrapping) and get the response through asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

How to do i change the website content language programmatically using asp.net c#?

https://www.tnpds.gov.in/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiTdU.png)

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.tnpds.gov.in");
        request.Method = "POST";
        Dictionary<string, string> postParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        postParams.Add("masterForm:languageSelectMenu:", "en");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 7.1; Trident/5.0)";
        request.Accept = "/";

        HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (resp.CharacterSet == null)
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            else
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet));
            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(data);
            resp.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no short way to do localization.
You can use google translate plugin or [nopcommerce api](https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/translations) for translating web pages to specific language.

Refer [Google Plugin article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/language-convertor-using-google-translator-plugin-in-Asp-Net/) and [Codeproject google plugin](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34794/Translate-Your-Website-to-Another-Language-using-G)  or [nopcommerce](https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/translations) for more details.